# How to populate multiple coordinates on map

Tags: community, google-map

I have two custom objects in Master-Detail relationship, there is a GeoLocation field on child object, now I have to display pin all the location of child record on the Master object page.
I am able to do this using API http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
but was wondering, would it be possible to download map and save it within Org,
and then using JavaScript, pin the locations.

I am not pro at JavaScript, and this could strange idea, but I have been asked avoid use of googleapis :(

Answer (score 1):

Soon, you won't even need Javascript. Check out the [apex:map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_map.htm) and [apex:mapMarker](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_mapMarker.htm) components. I believe they are in beta, but then again the same is the case for the `Geolocation` field type.